# Users are disconnected in 5/6 minutes

Tags: symfony, symfony-security

With Symfony 3.3.16, my users are disconnected in 5/6 minutes. I don't understand.

This problem is only in production (OVH), not in dev.

> session.gc_maxlifetime : 1440

`security.yml` :

```
security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User: bcrypt

    providers:
        database_users:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle\Entity\User

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern: ^/

            anonymous: true

            simple_form:
                username_parameter: _email
                authenticator: AppBundle\Security\Authenticator
                check_path: login
                login_path: login
                success_handler: AppBundle\Handler\AuthenticationSuccessHandler

            logout:
                path: logout
                handlers: [AppBundle\Handler\LogoutHandler]
                success_handler: AppBundle\Handler\LogoutSuccessHandler

    access_control:
        - { path: '^/administration', roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: '^/user', roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

In the symfony [configuration reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#cookie-lifetime), you can configure the session lifetime setting:

**cookie_lifetime**

> This determines the lifetime of the session - in seconds. The default
> value - null - means that the session.cookie_lifetime value from
> php.ini will be used. Setting this value to 0 means the cookie is
> valid for the length of the browser session.

**gc_maxlifetime**

This determines the number of seconds after which data will be seen as "garbage" and potentially cleaned up. Garbage collection may occur during session start and depends on gc_divisor and gc_probability.

Check their value in the `config.yml` and `config_prod.yml`

I understand you have already checked the the value of the php.ini value `session.gc_maxlifetime`